# Editing using SQL update row does not change anything and there are no errors

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to create a feature where a row is edited and updated but when I press my save button, there are no changes (the page just refreshes). Looking for solutions for a fix or to know what I am missing.

**Table Name: for_lease**

[image: 1]

Three files are being used for the update feature

**1. for_lease_edit.php**

[image: 2]

this is a snipped of my input field form:

```
<form action="for_lease_edit.php?i=<?php echo($rowProperty['leaseid']); ?>" method="post">
  'value  => (isset($_POST['lease_name'])) ? $_POST['lease_name'] : $rowProperty['lease_name'],
  'value' => (isset($_POST['lease_type'])) ? $_POST['lease_type'] : $rowProperty['lease_type'],
  'value' => (isset($_POST['lease_address'])) ? $_POST['lease_address'] : $rowProperty['lease_address'],
  'value' => (isset($_POST['lease_price'])) ? $_POST['lease_price'] : $rowProperty['lease_price'],
  'value' => (isset($_POST['lease_condition'])) ? $_POST['lease_condition'] : $rowProperty['lease_condition'],
  'value' => (isset($_POST['lease_description'])) ? $_POST['lease_description'] : $rowProperty['lease_description'],
</form>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
    <input type="submit" class="btn bg-color-dark-gold color-white form-control" name="submit" value="SAVE">
  </div>
```

**2. for_lease_edit.vc.php**

```
require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
    $dbConfig = new config_db();
    $db = $dbConfig->init();

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Property.mc.php");
  $mcProperty = new Property_MC();

  if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'SAVE')
  {
    $leaseid = $_GET['i'];
    $lease_name = $_POST['lease_name'];
    $lease_type = $_POST['lease_type'];
    $lease_address = $_POST['lease_address'];
    $lease_price = $_POST['lease_price'];
    $lease_condition = $_POST['lease_condition'];
    $lease_description = $_POST['lease_description'];

    $mcProperty->UpdateLease($db, $leaseid, $lease_type, $lease_name, $lease_address, $lease_price, $lease_condition, $lease_description);
  }
```

the **$leaseid = $_GET['i'];** gets its value from the form tag in the first table: **for_lease_edit.php?i=**

**3. Property.mc.php**

```
<?php

Class Property_MC {

   public function UpdateLease($db, $leaseid, $lease_type, $lease_name, $lease_address, $lease_price, $lease_condition, $lease_description) {

  $stmt = $db->prepare(
    " UPDATE for_lease
      SET  lease_type :lease_type, lease_name :lease_name, lease_address :lease_address, lease_price :lease_price, lease_condition :lease_condition, lease_description :lease_description
      WHERE leaseid = :leaseid "
  );

  $stmt->bindValue(':leaseid', $leaseid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(':lease_name', $lease_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(':lease_type', $lease_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(':lease_address', $lease_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(':lease_price', $lease_price, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(':lease_condition', $lease_condition, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(':lease_description', $lease_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->execute();
  $rowAffected = $stmt->rowCount();

  return $rowAffected;
}
}

?>
```

I am not sure which part am i missing for the update to work. At first glance it looks complete. Will appreciate any help

Comment: You are missing something in your update statements in `SET  lease_type :lease_type`!

Comment: what is this something missing in the update SQL?

Comment: Try `lease_type = :lease_type`

Comment: so thats what i am missing, thanks for pointing it out, added "=" to all of them and it worked.